# Group dates into weeks of the year, PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, datetime-format

I am looking to display events (custom post type) in Wordpress this is easy enough to do as they can be ordered from soonest to furtherest away.

However, it gets complicated when I want to display "W/C April 19".

For example there would essentially be a new 'events-row' for each week that contains an event during that week.

This I have literally 0 clue how to do, I'm currently using a foreach loop to display the events as opposed to a WP_Query.

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'order' => 'DESC'
) );

$posts = $query->posts;

if( $posts ){
    $groupByWeek = array(); foreach( $posts as $post ){
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $eventDateTime = get_field('event_date_time', $post->ID); //Get the Start Date & Time Group
        $eventStart = $eventDateTime['event_date_time_start']; //Get the event Start Date & Time
        $date =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i a', $eventStart); //Turn string into PHP DateTime
        
        $firstDayOfWeek = 1; //Define the first day of the week in PHP 'N' format

        $difference = ($firstDayOfWeek - $date->format('N')); //Find the difference between the first day and events day


        if ($difference > 1) { //If the difference is greater than 1
            $difference -= 7; //Take away 7 (1 week)
        }

        $date->modify("$difference days");

        $week = $date->format('W');

        if(!isset($groupByWeek[$week])){
            $groupByWeek[$week] = [];
        }

        $groupByWeek[$week][] = $post;
    }
}
```

$groupByWeek Dump:

```php
array(1) { 
    [21]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> object(WP_Post)#13970 (24) { 
            ["ID"]=> int(625) 
            ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2021-04-22 19:56:50" 
            ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2021-04-22 18:56:50" 
            ["post_content"]=> string(233) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " 
            ["post_title"]=> string(69) "Events Name that likely goes over two lines but lets cater for three!" 
        }
    }

    [20]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(WP_Post)#14271 (24) {
            ["ID"]=> int(635) 
            ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2021-04-22 19:55:08" 
            ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2021-04-22 18:55:08" 
            ["post_content"]=> string(233) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " 
            ["post_title"]=> string(69) "Events Name that likely goes over two lines but lets cater for three!"
        }
    }
}
```

So the code above correctly moves the events into their own Weekly array, now I am have to loop through this new array to display the events on the frontend and also the week commencing number. Which I am currently stuck at.

Desired Outcome:

```html
<div class="all-events events-container">
    <ul class="all-events-inner events-row">
        <li class="week-commencing">W/C Apr 19</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="all-events-inner events-row">
        <li class="week-commencing">W/C Apr 26</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="all-events-inner events-row">
        <li class="week-commencing">W/C May 03</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
        <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Ali_k I've added some HTML for the desired outcome so you can understand what I mean better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need too much code to do it, You just need to find if the current post belongs to a specific week (number of the week in a year), then create a small logic to display additional markup based on that.

```
if ($posts) : ?>
    <div class="all-events events-container">
        <ul class="all-events-inner events-row">

            <?php
            // This will save the week that is being displayed
            $current_week = false;
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>
                <?php
                // Get event start date
                $start_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_date_time_start', true);
                // Find out this event week
                $week = date('WY', strtotime($start_date));

                // Check if this is the first time we are handling this week
                if ($week !== $current_week) {
                    // Store the current week so that we don't show the same output once again until next week
                    $current_week = $week;
                    // Get the first day of this week
                    $dateTime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)));
                    $monday = $dateTime->modify('Monday this week');
                ?>
                    <li class="week-commencing">W/C <?php echo $monday->format('M d'); ?></li>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <li class="col-4 event">Blah blah stuff goes here</li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: This works 90% correctly, whatever you've done with the Week Commecing stuff almost ends that term in the foreach as it doesn't display the ```<li>``` with Blah blah in unless I include a copy of that line inside the if statement which isn't great.

Comment: Could be an error causing this, have you checked your logs? can you share them?